# Seleccionar imagenes de la base de datos sqlserver php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Tengo un query que selecciona información de la base de datos pero no logro imprimir las imágenes en pantalla, la dirección de la carpeta de imágenes están en

```
\\192.168.10.129\sapshared\FOTOS\KennedyDB
```

pero la aplicación la estoy corriendo desde `192.168.10.134`, aquí les dejo mi código:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Prueba de PHP</title>
 </head>
 <body>


<?php
$serverName = "192.168.10.134";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"**********", "UID"=>"**", "PWD"=>"***");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

$sql = "SELECT TOP 200 Itemcode, Itemname, PicturName FROM OITM ";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}
echo "<table border = '1' class = 'table0' > \n"; 

echo "<tr><td>Itemcode</td><td>Itemname</td><td>Picture</td></tr> \n";
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo "<tr><td>$row[Itemcode]</td><td>$row[Itemname]</td><td>$row[PicturName] </td></tr> \n"; 
}
echo "</table> \n"; 


sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
?>


 </body>
</html>
```

Así como está, en el campo `picturname` solo muestra el nombre de la imagen ej. `image.jpg`

Comment: Puedes probar a cambiar **$row[PicturName]** por **<img src='/sapshared/FOTOS/KennedyDB/$row[PicturName]'>** de la ruta no estoy muy seguro.

Comment: La carpeta se encuentra en otro servidor @track3r

Comment: Pues en lugar de la carpeta que he puesto, la ruta a las imágenes, es lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><img src='\\192.168.10.129\sapshared\FOTOS\KennedyDB' alt='$row[PicturName]'> </td>
```

Quizá las \ tengas que duplicarlas, y ponerle \\\\ delante de la ip, y al resto de contrabarras simples duplicarlas también \\

Tienes que comprobar también que el servidor php tiene acceso a esa ruta local y a la carpeta concreta para que pueda mostrar las img.

Comment: tengo mi servidor iis en el ip 192.168.10.16 el hace consultas a la base de datos que se encuentra en 192.168.10.134 pero las imágenes están en 192.168.10.129

Comment: mira @vera lo puse de esta <img src='file://192.168.10.129/sapshared/FOTOS/KennedyDB/$row[PicturName]'  height = '100' width = '100'    ></td> y ya se ven las imagenes pero solo en el servidor como localhost y solo las muestra internet explorer

Comment: creo que si le pones el "file" delante sólo lo verás en localhost como dices que te está pasando. 
La teoría dice que si el atributo 'src' lleva a una unidad de red, como es el caso tuyo, cualquiera con acceso a la red y con permisos sobre esa carpeta puede acceder a ella. Asegúrate de que esa carpeta de fotos tiene permisos de lectura y escritura para todos los usuarios de la red (o al menos para el grupo o usuarios que vayan a usar la aplicación web).
No he trasteado nunca IIS, quizá haya algún campo u opción de permisos para ficheros multimedia (es sólo una suposición eh...)